# Сохранить ImageView в директорию программы

Tags: java, android, imageview

Как я могу сохранить картинку из ImageView в директорию программы и получить путь к ней? Чтобы после перезапуска программы это картинку автоматически подгружало

Comment: Скорее всего вас устроит к-л библиотека, которая делает это автоматически. Например Glide.

Comment: Я добавил вызов функции в Activity Create, но теперь программа вылетает без любых ошибок. Вот функция: private void LoadAvatarImagePath()
    {
        Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(profileImage);
    }

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка у вас в логах таки есть. И скорее всего она в том, что вы невалидный адрес картинки пытаетесь загрузить. Адрес должен с `https://` начинаться, по идее.